# Hoarding wealth and resources

Tags: yoga-sutras

This question is inspired from the current demonetization that is happening.

I remember that Patanjali Yoga Sutras talk about *Aparigraha* which means non-accumulation. This refers to non-accumulation of thoughts and emotions i.e. not holding onto things and letting go. Also, in the physical realm, it refers to non-accumulation of unnecessary resources including wealth. The benefit of *Aparigraha* is said to be that the knowledge of other people and past lives come to you.

Which other scriptures talk about hoarding of wealth and resources?

Comment: Our Scriptures extol the greatness of charity which is just opposite of accumulating wealth that is beyond necessity.

Answer (score 1):

In this regard, the following excerpt from the Śiva Mahā-Purāṇa maybe considered.

> [Chapter 13](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225558.html), Vidyeśvara-saṃhitā, Śiva-purāṇa
>
> ग्रहीताहिगृहीतस्य दानाद्वै तपसा तथा । पापसंशोधनं कुर्यादन्यथा रौरवं
> व्रजेत् ॥ ७१ ॥
>
> > 71. The receiver of a gift must expiate for his sin by means of austerities or by making gifts to others. Otherwise, he will fall into
> >     the Raurava hell.
>
> ---
>
> आत्मवित्तं त्रिधा कुर्याद्धर्मवृद्ध्यात्मभोगतः । नित्यं नैमित्तकं
> काम्यं कर्म कुर्यात्तु धर्मतः ॥ ७२ ॥ वित्तस्य वर्धनं
> कुर्याद्वृद्ध्यंशेन हि साधकः । हितेन मितमे ध्येन भोगं भोगांशतश्चरेत् ॥
> ७३ ॥
>
> 72. & 73. **Everyone shall set apart a third of his wealth for Dharma,
>     another third for Vṛddhi (flourishing), and the rest for his Bhoga
>     (enjoyment). With the part intended for Dharma, he shall perform the
>     three rites of virtue viz. Nitya (daily prayers etc.), Naimittika
>     (casual acts of piety), and Kāmya (specific rites for the fulfillment
>     of desires). By means of the second part, he shall increase his
>     wealth. By utilizing the third part he shall enjoy with restraint in
>     pure and wholesome ways.**
>
> ---
>
> कृष्यर्जिते दशांशं हि देयं पापस्य शुद्धये । शेषेण कुर्याद्धर्मादि
> अन्यथा रौरवं व्रजेत् ॥ ७४ ॥
>
> > 74. One-tenth of the wealth acquired by agricultural operations must first be given to charity (before making the three-fold divisions) in
> >     order to wipe off the sin. He can utilize the rest as mentioned
> >     before. Otherwise, he shall fall into Raurava (hell).
>
> ---
>
> अथवा पापबुद्धिः स्यात्क्षयं वा सत्यमेष्यति । वृद्धिवाणिज्यके
> देयष्षडंशो हि विचक्षणैः ॥ ७५ ॥
>
> > 75. Or he is sure to be evil-minded hastening towards his own certain ruin. Sensible persons acquiring much wealth by way of usury or
> >     trading activities must likewise give away a sixth of that wealth in
> >     charity (before making the threefold divisions).
>
> ---
>
> शुद्धप्रतिग्रहे देयश्चतुर्थांशो द्विजोत्तमैः । अकस्मादुत्थितेऽर्थे हि
> देयमर्धं द्विजोत्तमैः ॥ ७६ ॥
>
> > 76. Excellent brahmins, accepting monetary gifts from decent people, shall give away a fourth of that wealth in charity. They shall
> >     likewise give away half in charity in case of an unexpected windfall.
>
> ---
>
> असत्प्रतिग्रहसर्वं दुर्दानं सागरे क्षिपेत् । आहूय दानं
> कर्तव्यमात्मभोगसमृद्धये ॥ ७७ ॥
>
> > 77. If a brahmin accepts a monetary gift from an indecent fellow he shall give away the entire amount in charity. A defiled gift shall be
> >     thrown into the sea. It is more creditable if one invites people and
> >     makes gifts to them. One’s own enjoyment gains by it.
>
> ---
>
> पृष्टं सर्वं सदा देयमात्मशक्त्यनुसारतः । जन्मांतरे ऋणी हि स्याददत्ते
> पृष्टवस्तुनि ॥ ७८ ॥
>
> > 78. **A man must give others what they beg of him according to his ability. If a thing requested for is not given he will be indebted to
> >     that extent even in his next birth.**
>
> English Translation by J.L. Shastri

Therefore, we see:

- Scriptures prohibit any kind of unnecessary and adharmic hoarding of wealth and resources.
- The gained wealth has to be divided for each, Dharma, Artha, and the Kama, appropriately, as per scriptural injunctions.
- Instead of "hoarding", charity and other pious activities derived from it are recommended and deemed Dharmic.
- Overall, it must be noted, whatever wealth & resources is being earned, saved, spent and consumed - all of it must be according to priciples of Dharma, as laid above, and in various dharma-shastras, and not otherwise.