# What portion of wealth was given away in yajnas?

Tags: yajna

It is mentioned in Ramayana that a king can at most tax one-sixth of their praja’s earnings. One of the goals of a Kshatriya is to accumulate artha but not at the expense of dharma and vice versa.

Since hoarding of wealth is a [sin](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/51210/31000), and more generally leads to an inefficient macroeconomy in the kingdom, the system needs to correct itself with redistribution of wealth. A large scale way in which this happened is via yajnas where kings would give away a lot of riches in the form of gold, weapons, cows, grains etc to the needy praja.

Do our scriptures state what portion of the wealth should be given away in these yajnas and do they mention how frequently should such yajnas be held?

Comment: Again, can the downvoter leave a feedback to let me know how I can improve my question?